# Correct Formatting for Json from PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get my JSON output like this.

```
{"allterms":[{"group":{"Name":"Test 1"},{"group":{"Name":"Test2","Id":"298"}}]
```

My current code is

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
$rows['allterms']['group'][] = $r;   
}
```

Which gives me this

```
{"allterms":{"group":[{"Name":"Test1", "Id":"1740"},{"Name":"Test2","Id":"631"}}]
```

How can I adjust my code so that each item has a parent term `group`.

Comment: Try `$rows['allterms'][]['group']`, should give you an array of objects

Comment: Many thanks Kingkero, since it wasn't formed as answer I couldn't accept it as the right one so I accepted AD7six's below.  But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the loop like so:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $rows['allterms'][]['group'] = $r;   
}
```

which will generate:

```
array(
    'allterms' => array(
        0 => array(
            'group' => array(...),
        ),
        1 => array(
            'group' => array(...),
        )
        ...
    )
```

which as json will be:

```
{
  "allterms": [
    {
      "group": {
        {
          "Name": "Test1",
          "Id": "1740"
        },
    {
      "group": {
        {
          "Name": "Test2",
          "Id": "631"
        }
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function from PHP.

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    array_push($rows['allterms'], $r);   
}
```